# OSX How to tell when a user plugs/unplugs a headphone with a microphone built in

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I have created an app that records audio from the user-- but I am having a problem when if the user plugs into the headphone jack with a headset that contains a microphone, it kills my recording.  I theorize that my app is still trying to listen on the built in microphone, and when the new microphone is plugged in the computer only allows input from that microphone.

I'm not too sure, but I figure if I can create a listener that tells me when a headphone is plugged in, that should help me a lot in finding where the issue lies.

Has anybody seen this problem before?

Comment: Okay so update, when I log my current devices, even with the headphone/integrated microphone plugged in, it doesn't display as a avcapturedevice-- even though it definitely is taking in input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can just check the AVCaptureDeviceInputSource, and when a headphone with a mic is plugged in, that property is changed from imic to emic (internal to external).  The AVCaptureDevice remains as "built-in", but the key is that the InputSource changes.